# Redirecting from example.com to example.com/drupal

Tags: redirection

I have Drupal 7 installed in a ./drupal directory in my web server (shared host).

I would like www.mysite.net to be redirect to www.mysite.net/drupal in a transparent way for visitors. They should see in their navigation bar www.mysite.net instead of www.mysite.net/drupal.

I also want clean URLs to work. To make clean URLs work, I have edited my drupal/.htaccess file and uncomment this line:

```
RewriteBase /drupal
```

I read a lot of posts about having Drupal in a subdirectory, but the suggested solutions don't work (they cause an internal server error, or problems with CSS and images). Most of these tutorials are based in 2 htaccess file, one in the root directory and one in the directory where Drupal is installed. They also required to change `$base_url` in settings.php.

Answer (score 2):

Try in .htaccess and make sure `RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteRule !^drupal/ drupal/%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Then try `example.com` if this maps to `example.com/drupal/`

I think `RewriteBase /drupal` will not produce the result.

It should be either `RewriteBase /` or commented in the case above.

---

I have gone through this issues deeply and fixed on my end.

Put following rule to your .htaccess on root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^drupal/ drupal/index.php?q=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The default .htaccess of Drupal is restored to original.

After this setup css and image will fail those are depending on `$base_path`.
I then override `$base_path` value from `/drupal/` to `/` using `hook_init()`

```
function my_custom_module_init(){
   global $base_path;
   $base_path = '/';
}
```

And this is fixed.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but after adding the rewrite rule on the root htaccess and restore the default htacess in /drupal, I get a error 500 internal server error (no more details are given). I don't understand what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

The following worked for me, but keep in mind that the issue is still in the form of several bugs, that were not yet addressed as of v. 7.14. It involves something with bootstrap.inc, and updated .htaccess between v. 6 and v. 7. I do not fully grasp modRewrite syntax, so particular instructions could be not as efficient. I just used what worked for me (at godaddy.com hosting).

1. Place Drupal installation in `/drupal/` directory (or whichever, adjust accordingly).
2. Set `$base_url` in `settings.php` to your domain (`$base_url = 'http://example.net';`).
3. Create `.htaccess` file in the root directory and place following in it:

   ```
   # Don't show directory listings for URLs which map to a directory.
   Options -Indexes

   # Follow symbolic links in this directory.
   Options +FollowSymLinks

   ReWriteEngine On
   ReWriteBase /

   # Exclude other directories from rewrite rules
   RewriteRule ^(exclude1|exclude2) - [L]

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net$ [NC]
   ReWriteRule !^drupal/   - [C]
   ReWriteRule ^(.*)  drupal/$1  [L]
   ```

   **Note:** Up to this point, instructions work the same for Drupal 6 (it would be complete now).
4. In the `/drupal/.htaccess` file find the section starting with following comments:

   ```
   # Pass all requests not referring directly to files in the filesystem to
   # index.php. Clean URLs are handled in drupal_environment_initialize().
   ```

   Comment out this string (to keep it in case the issue shall be fixed):

   ```
   RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
   ```

   And add following line (from drupal 6):

   ```
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
   ```

Comment: I've been trying to get clean urls to work forever; I think it's step 4 that did it for me. Thanks.