# After setting $base_url, I can only access the front page

Tags: redirection

I have Drupal installed in a subdirectory of `public_html` on BlueHost.

It looks like this: `/www/drupal7/mywebsite`.

I want to run the site out of the `mywebsite` subdirectory instead of `www`.  However, I want the URL to appear to be http://mywebsite.com.

Here is the suggested `.htaccess` configuration from BlueHost.  This is the `.htaccess` for the `www/` directory; I am using the default Drupal 7 `.htaccess` in Drupal's subdirectory.

```
# BlueHost.com 
# .htaccess main domain to subdirectory redirect 
# Do not change this line. 
RewriteEngine on 
# Change example.com to be your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdirectory/ 
# Don't change the following two lines. 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain. 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdirectory/$1 
# Change example.com to be your main domain again. 
# Change 'subdirectory' to be the directory you will use for your main domain 
# followed by / then the main file for your site, index.php, index.html, etc. 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdirectory/index.html [L]
```

This successfully allows me to use Drupal from the subdirectory, but the URLs look like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/drupal7/mywebsite/PAGE

But I want it to look like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/PAGE

[This post on Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/comment/765630#comment-765630) suggests that the $base_url must be set in `default/settings.php`.  I set the `$base_url` to "http://mywebsite.com"; however, when I do this, whatever link I click, I am redirected to the front page.

Is there an additional step?  What am I missing?

Comment: you need to include the directory name in base url like "http://mywebsite.com/mywebsite"

Comment: @Bala When I include the directory name in the base URL, then the directory name shows up in the URL.  How can I serve the pages properly **without** showing the directory name in the URL?

Comment: @PatrickKenny why dont you use the default Drupal `.htaccess` file ?

Comment: @PatrickKenny Do you have access to change the apache web server configuration files on your bluehost account?

Comment: @NikhilM I am using the default Drupal .htaccess file.  But I need another .htaccess file in my public_html directory to rewrite the URLs to point to the Drupal subdirectory.

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6313/redirecting-from-example-com-to-example-com-drupal?rq=1

Comment: The problem with the redirection to your homepage could be linked to Clean URLs. I would suggest to disable it first, configure your website, and enable again.

Comment: @PatrickKenny have yout it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the answer from Oleg Ivanov would work. However, if you want to tackle this with a .htaccess approach, the following works for me. Find and replace `SUBDIRECTORY` with your subdirectory.

Amend your Drupal's .htaccess with the following:

```
RewriteBase /

# homepage redirect
RewriteRule ^$ /SUBDIRECTORY/index.php?q= [L]

# if directory or regular file...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/favicon.ico
# stop here
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# if a regular file in SUBDIRECTORY directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/SUBDIRECTORY/%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule .* SUBDIRECTORY/$0 [L]

# Redirect everything to /SUBDIRECTORY
RewriteRule .* /SUBDIRECTORY/index.php?q=$0 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the default `.htaccess` shipped with drupal and

1. Make sure line 110 is commented like this

   `# RewriteBase /`
2. Uncomment and edit line 106 to read like this

   `RewriteBase /drupal7/mywebsite`

Comment: I tried this but I'm still having the same problem-- whatever link I click, the URL changes but the front page content is displayed.

Comment: @PatrickKenny can you just remove the base_url form your settings.php and try ?

Comment: When I remove the base_url, then the pages are loaded properly, but the URLs look like this: `http://www.mywebsite.com/drupal7/mywebsite/PAGE`

Comment: I think some rewrite rule will work try this `RewriteRule ^drupal7/mywebsite/(.*)$ index.php$1 [R,L]` use this in line 117 of drupal htaccess

Answer (score 1):

I host several of my Drupal websites on BlueHost, and I've achieved basically what you're asking without changing any of `.htaccess` files:

here's what I do - 
(I have a separate Drupal installation for each site for a number of reasons, although I believe the same can be done with a multi-site install)

I have a Drupal installation in `/public_html/mywebsite`;

I add http://mywebsite.com to my account via "Assign Domain", as an Addon Domain -

in Step 4 - "Choose Addon Directory and Sub-domain" -  I choose
"Use an existing directory" (from a list of sub-directories under `public_html`) - `mywebsite`; (it also appears as `mywebsite.mymainaccountdomain.com` - so be it, I just don't use it)

after all the changes propagate through BlueHost servers' "insides" (sometimes takes up to 15 minutes, especually for 'www' redirect to catch on) -

my site is accessible as both http://mywebsite.com and http://www.mywebsite.com and all its pages load as expected - http://www.mywebsite.com/page and so on

hope this helps

Comment: This is a straightforward approach, except apparently it doesn't work if you are trying to re-assign the first domain registered with the account (the primary domain).  I talked with Bluehost support, but apparently the first domain cannot be redirected from the UI.

Comment: unfortunately - yes, it seems that nothing can be done through their UI for the primary domain

Comment: @Patrick - did jwal's suggestion work for you?
I tried that approach for my 'primary' domain - used the BlueHost's .htaccess from the initial post for `/public_html` folder and jwal's one for my
`/public_html/mywebsite` folder - but I'm getting the same URL that you were getting at the beginning - 

`http://www.mywebsite.com/mywebsite/PAGE`

is there anything I'm missing?